# Make a button to create boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create boxes inside of a `div`(The `div` here is `box`) whenever the user clicks the button. I have done the following so far, but no boxes are created.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
      .myDiv {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-color: blue;
          }
      #box {
        width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
        border: solid black;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The onclick Event</h1>
        <button id ="theBoxes" >Creating boxes</button>
        <div id = "box"></div>
        <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("theBoxes");
        x.addEventListener("click", myFunction)
          function myFunction() {
            var box = document.createElement('div');
            box.classList.add('myDiv');
            document.body.appendChild(box); 
          }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'create a box'?

Comment: `myfunction` should be `myFunction` and you are adding class whereas you defined ID in the CSS ... simple typo issues [voting to close]

Comment: @TemaniAfif , After editing very small typos, the code still does not create a box. I think there is some issue with the myFunction.

Comment: you edited one typo .. you are adding a class and you are defining an ID in the CSS so the box have no style so you won't see them

Comment: i.e. `#myDiv {` => `.myDiv {`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("theBoxes");
x.addEventListener("click", myFunction)
function myFunction() {
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.classList.add('myDiv');
  document.body.appendChild(box); 
}
```

```css
.myDiv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#box {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  border: solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The onclick Event</h1>
        <button id ="theBoxes" >Creating boxes</button>
        <div id = "box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your code is working, unfortunately `border-color: blue` in `myDiv` doesn't work and the box also added outside your div `#box`.

So I modify a bit your code by adding `position: absolute` in `#box` and `border: 1px solid blue` in `.myDiv`.

Comment: Thank-you. This helps!